# Use a loop to generate a user to enter 10 numbers on seperate lines using Python, then write them to a file

Tags: python

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I keep getting an invalid syntax error on the line with the `for` loop.

```
def main():

    outfile = open('numbers.txt','w')
    outfile.write[input('Enter a value: ')
                  for i in range(10)]:
        print(i)
    outfile.close()

main()
```

Comment: Is this the indentation you have in your script?

Comment: `write` is a method, it needs parenthesis around the argument.  That line shouldn't end a colon.  And your `print` attempt won't work as you expect.   Lastly, you can't write a list to a file that way.  The entire approach seems flawed, however.

Comment: I voted to close as "Too Broad" on the basis that complete answers would either have to explain a great deal of content to you so you could figure this out yourself or would just do the assignment for you. I highly recommend finding some basic Python learning material and practice at combining simple elements of code to produce more complex behavior.

Comment: That was unnecessary, as I am in a beginner Python class and i was going by my textbook when writing this code. I came here as a last resort for help, as that is what this site is for. My code wasn't completely terrible, just missing a few things so thank you for kicking someone when they were down and actually trying to learn the material.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever it is you are trying to do with that `outfile.write` line has two main syntax errors that you need to be careful about.

First, `write` is a method, and you are not treating it as such. So you need to use `()`. Furthermore, remove the `:`. I am not sure what you are trying to do with those colons and the print statement. But that is not valid syntax. On second inspection, it seems like you are trying to print each `i`. With the methodology you are using to capture your input by using a comprehension, you cannot print the output like that, as the `i` is no longer in scope by the time you are printing that `i`.

Furthermore, you will not be able to write a list to a file with the methodology you are using. So, chances are you are looking to write the string representation of those list values. You should use the `join` method to do this:

```
outfile.write(' '.join([input('Enter a value: ') for i in range(10)]))
```

To explain the `join`. What this will do is take the list you created and create a string out of your list entries, by separating each entry by a space. So if for example you have a list as:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Calling `' '.join()` on it, will create a string separated by a space as:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

So, your final functional code looks like:

```
def main():

    outfile = open('numbers.txt','w')
    outfile.write(' '.join([input('Enter a value: ') for i in range(10)]))
    outfile.close()

main()
```

It is important to note, that a good practice here when dealing with file objects is to use a context manager, which would change your code to look like:

```
def main():
    with open('numbers.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(' '.join([input('Enter a value: ') for i in range(10)]))
```

The context manager is denoted by using the [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement. Some more suggested reading on file objects can be found in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Comment: Forgot to mention that the `i` is not in scope at `print(i)`

Comment: @cricket_007 It would be if the `for` line was indented reasonably and there wasn't a weirdo `]` in the middle of it.

Comment: @cricket_007 TBH I had no idea how to interpret what that `print(i)` was doing. On a second look, it seems like OP is trying to output each `i`. So yes, I will edit to mention that.

Comment: @jpmc26 the `i` appears to be intended as part of the list comprehension.

Comment: @cricket_007 I suppose so. On the other hand, that colon makes it look like it's supposed to be a non-comprehension `for` loop. Perhaps it started as one and the OP is trying to modify it into the other.

Comment: I don't get a syntax with the .join line, however it still isn't actually writing it to the text file.

Comment: @SZumpf The code works. I tested it. Nonetheless, I updated my answer to explain join more and provide the code that works.

Comment: Don't use `open` like that. At *least* enclose it in `try`/`finally` properly if you're going to use it that way, but you *should* use it as a context manager: `with open('numbers.txt','w') as outfile:`.

Comment: @jpmc26 The point of this answer was to keep it as simple as possible. Because OP is clearly new to the language. I personally don't like resorting to using `finally`. If I use a `try/except`, I will be explicit with the type of exception to catch. In this case it is too broad to start going down the path of providing examples of what to catch. Furthermore, while my go-to is to use a context manager in these situations, again, the point was to keep it simple for the OP to understand. Also, the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods of the context manager perform the open and close respectively.

Comment: @jpmc26 Throwing the suggestion of using a context manager adds more than the OP needs to know at this point. Again, they are just starting out. By just telling the OP to use `with`, opens another path of having to explain why that should be done. Which would then make the answer even longer. In the end, I understand what you are saying, and yes, using a context manager is preferable. It should not take away from the fact that the file is being handled correctly in that it is being opened and closed explicitly. Conclusively, I think your downvote here is a bit excessive.

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion, but I generally downvote answers that showcase well known bad practices that are easily avoidable. New developers will learn (or not learn) from these. You don't have to explain everything in your answer if you present the correct way, though; you can link out to existing resources for that.

Comment: @jpmc26 :) Sure. FWIW I added a note about it at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is the same as you have here, you have two issues:

`outfile.write()` Needs to have parentheses since it is a function call.

Your indentation is messed up. To have a for loop, you should have something like

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

If you have brackets like you do in your code, you'll have a list comprehension, but the syntax should be like the following:

```
outfile.write([input('Enter a value: ' for _ in range(10)])
```

Answer (score 0):

The first error is with the line for i in range(10)]. It should be for i in range(10).

The next errors are occurring on the line directly prior to the for loop:

`outfile.write[input('Enter a value: ')` should be `outfile.write(raw_input('Enter a value: '))`.

`[` needed to be `(`, and `raw_input` was substituted for `input` so as to write a `string` value to the file.

Finally, so as to request input 10 times from the user to write each to a new line of the file, outfile's write method needed to be placed in the loop

The final formatted code would look like this:

```
def main():

    outfile = open('numbers.txt','w')
    for i in range(10):
        outfile.write(raw_input('Enter a value: ') + '\n')
    outfile.close()

main()
```

Comment: I am getting syntax that raw_input is not defined

Comment: If you are using Python 3.x, raw_input was renamed to input

Comment: Yes, I am using Python 3.4. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer was helpful or worked for you, please accept it by checking the green checkmark.